# Convert decimal to binary and find the maximum number of consecutive 1's in the binary

Tags: beginner, algorithm, ruby

Task: given a base- 10 integer, n, convert it to binary (base-2). Then find and print the base- 10 integer denoting the maximum number of consecutive 1's in n's binary representation.

What can you say about my implementation of the problem?

```
n = gets.strip.to_i
array = []
while n > 0
  array.push(n % 2)    
  n = n / 2 
end

counter = 0
consec = []
len = array.length

array.each_with_index do |x, index|
  if x == 1
    counter += 1
    consec.push(counter) if index + 1 == len
  else
    consec.push(counter) if counter > 0
    counter = 0
  end
end

puts consec.sort[-1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You solution looks good for a procedural one -- something similar would be the correct way to do this in, say, C.

That said, and assuming this isn't considered "cheating" for the problem at hand, if you're using ruby, you might as well take advantage of ruby's facilities.  Assuming the input number is `n`, all you need to do is:

```
n.to_s(2).scan(/1+/).max_by(&:size).size
```

or, even more tersely, taking advantage of how strings are compared (ie, `"11" > "1"` and `"111" > "11"`, etc):

```
n.to_s(2).scan(/1+/).max.size
```

`to_s(2)` converts to the binary string, `scan` finds all runs of `1`s, `max_by` finds the longest of those, and the final `size` tells you how long that is, as a decimal.

Comment: Great answer! I just wasn't aware of the to_s(2) and scan methods. Decided not to google anything and figure it all out myself. But I was aware of 'split' so it was possible for me to do 'split('0')' instead of 'scan(/1+/)'.  Also I believe you could use just 'max.size' instead of 'max_by(&:size).size' ?

Answer (score 0):

1 You could check the sequence count logic while converting the decimal to binary. This would avoid iterating through the array twice.

2 You have iterated the array twice, and the sorted the array which means there is one more iteration

3 The whole thing could be figured in a single iteration by keeping a count of consecutive one in decimal to binary logic

```
<?php


$handle = fopen("php://stdin", "r");

fscanf($handle, "%d", $n);
$maxcount = 0;

$tempcount = 0;

while ($n > 1) {
    $rem = $n % 2;
    if ($rem == 0) {
        if ($tempcount > $maxcount) {
            $maxcount = $tempcount;
        }
        $tempcount = 0;
    } else {
        $tempcount += 1;
    }
    $n = $n / 2;
}

if ($tempcount > $maxcount) {
    $maxcount = $tempcount;
}
print $maxcount;


?>
```